# Two variable function equations

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, functional-equations

Is there a good resource for learning two variable functions and where can I find some problems about two variable functional equations?
I have already searched AOPS and some other simiar websites but I didn't find anything...
Here is the problem I was struggling with
Find all functions $f: \mathbb {R}^+ \times \mathbb {R}^+ \to \mathbb {R}^+$ that satisfy the following conditions for all positive real numbers $x,y,z:$
$$f\left ( f(x,y),z \right )=x^2y^2f(x,z)$$$$f\left ( x,1+f(x,y) \right ) \ge x^2 + xyf(x,x)$$

Comment: Do you have a particular problem of this type you are struggling with? If so, please post it!

Comment: Find all functions $f: \mathbb {R}^+ \times \mathbb {R}^+ \to \mathbb {R}^+$ that satisfy the following conditions for all positive real numbers $x,y,z:$
$$f\left ( f(x,y),z \right )=x^2y^2f(x,z)$$$$f\left ( x,1+f(x,y) \right ) \ge x^2 + xyf(x,x)$$

Comment: Two-variable functions is not a field that deserves to be singled out. Say you see an equation $x^2+2x-3=0$, and suppose you don't know how to solve it. Suppose you decide to search for a book about solving equations that have 2 as their second coefficient. You will search in vain, no matter how long and hard. Also, this is _not_ because we don't know how to solve this particular equation. Same thing here.